# Multiple fonts in a website

Tags: blog, fonts

I have been creating a [blog](http://www.apptec.net) and now its almost done. I am thinking of adding fonts to it. I am curious if having more than 1 font in a website makes it look unprofessional? I understand that it is a personal opinion of a person how the site should look but my site is a blog so I want to consider how visitors might feel seeing multiple fonts on a website. Does it look standard? In short: How many fonts should one use so that readability does not get affected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In its present form, this question does not meet the [Webmasters quality guidelines](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) - can you revise your question to address a specific problem that you face? (e.g. "How many fonts can I use before readability is affected?")

Comment: Sure. I have done it.

Comment: Some good answers here, but for future reference, this sort of question's probably more appropriate for gd.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking use no more than two fonts on a web page. All you should need is a titling font and a body copy font with some different weights like bold and italic.

That said, you may also find you need additional fonts for specialist call outs or quotes (sometimes the italicized version of the body font just doesn't quite cut it), but you should use these additional fonts **very infrequently** and always in similar circumstances on the page - they should have a recognisable function.

The more fonts on a page the harder it is to read - it's that simple really..

This article from [go media zine](http://www.gomediazine.com/design-articles/technique-theory/rule-one-limit-your-fonts/) gives a good overview of the topic.

Comment: Yep. As with most things in design, less is more. For novice designers, I'd stick with no more than 2 typefaces--one display type and one body type. You also want these typefaces to have a good amount of contrast between them instead of pairing up similar styled typefaces. A good way to go is to match a serif type with a sans serif type. Also, using a very heavy display type against a light body type is a good way to contrast headings with body text. Besides this, just assign different font styles within the same type family for different page elements.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to delve into typography for this...

The basic idea is to convey not just meaning but emotions with fonts as well.

If you can choose 2-3 fonts that harmonize, and can convey meaning with emotion, then the answer is NO. It won't make your site unprofessional.

However using hosted webfonts can affect the loading speed of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I like having a different font for the headings.

BTW, have you seen the new and huge font collection from Google ?

http://www.google.com/webfonts

I've spent hours just watching them ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Typography is a pretty amazing topic if you know how to create one.

Mixing fonts to give an artistic looks, is never bad.

More than choosing multiple fonts, the **color choice** of fonts plays the major role. 
*5 fonts in same color will not look as attractive as a `color-perfection` out of a single font.*

Another main thing you should consider is the **boundary**. Do not mix up fonts with in a same boundary. Like, same paragraph giving same semantic meaning to it.

Rest? just **play around** with free mind, any consistent design you create may or may not consists of multiple fonts.